# Remove pts from last command

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I'm trying to remove the username and pts columns from last outputs I only want the output to show IP, Date, Times and Duration.

I'm have it down to:

```
last -i | head -5 | grep -v "still logged in"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that working? if it's not, what exactly are the problems with it? What is the output and why isn't it like you want it?

Comment: It was showing:


root     pts/5        IP    Thu Aug  4 15:20 - 16:24  (01:04)
root     pts/3        IP    Thu Aug  4 15:06 - 16:24  (01:17)

Where I wanted everything to the right of IP.

Comment: I've figured out that I can get it to do what I want using awk:

last -i | head -3 | grep -v "still logged in" | awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}'

Though that is quite cumbersome, is there anyway to shorten it?